# Interceptor for {..} has thrown exception, unwinding now org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message

Tags: jaxb, cxf, jax-ws

I am using a web service (https://cloud.mysond.it/service-ejb/FatturaElettronicaService?wsdl) and trying to use the method to import a document in the cloud, but when I try Eclipse gives me the error in the title, related to apache.cxf, java.net.ConnectException, java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException. Error is always "Could not send Message".

This is my servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

        String directoryPath = "C:\\Users\\Utente\\Desktop\\";
        
        
        
        Utente user = new Utente();
        
        
        //prova per invio documento singolo
        String fileName = request.getParameter("fileName");
        
        
        user.setCodiceAzienda("Gamma");
        user.setUsername("gamma");
        user.setPassword("gamma");
        
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(directoryPath + fileName));
        byte[] bb = new byte[in.available()];
        in.read(bb);
        in.close();
        
        DocImportPaItem ddc = new DocImportPaItem();
        ddc.setUtente(user);
        ddc.setFileName(fileName);
        ddc.setXmlDoc(bb);
        ddc.setSignAndSand(false);
        
        
        try {
            FatturaElettronicaServiceService service1 = new FatturaElettronicaServiceService();
            FatturaElettronicaService port1 = service1.getFatturaElettronicaServicePort();
            System.out.println(port1);            
            MysondInfo mmi = port1.importFeAttivo(ddc);
            System.out.println("-testImportFeAttivo: "  + mmi.getEsito() + " - " + mmi.getDescrizione());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

System.out.println(port1); print this: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy@2900c150
The error started within this line:

MysondInfo mmi = port1.importFeAttivo(ddc);

This is the extended error:

Interceptor for {http://ws.mysond.it/}FatturaElettronicaServiceService#{http://ws.mysond.it/}importFeAttivo has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HttpClientHTTPConduit$HttpClientWrappedOutputStream.isConnectionAttemptCompleted(HttpClientHTTPConduit.java:436)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HttpClientHTTPConduit$HttpClientWrappedOutputStream$1.canWrite(HttpClientHTTPConduit.java:464)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HttpClientHTTPConduit$HttpClientWrappedOutputStream$1.write(HttpClientHTTPConduit.java:474)
at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:51)
at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.unBuffer(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:89)
at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:63)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.flushBuffer(UTF8XmlOutput.java:386)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.text(UTF8XmlOutput.java:339)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Base64Data.writeTo(Base64Data.java:282)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.text(UTF8XmlOutput.java:280)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.leafElement(XMLSerializer.java:319)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$PcdataImpl.writeLeafElement(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:139)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.writeLeafElement(TransducedAccessor.java:216)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:92)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:327)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:659)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:126)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:327)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:659)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:126)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:123)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:93)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:295)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:302)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:38)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:457)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:268)
at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:196)
at jakarta.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:80)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.writeObject(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:642)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.marshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:244)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.write(DataWriterImpl.java:238)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:118)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:68)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:528)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:439)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:354)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:312)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140)
at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy42.importFeAttivo(Unknown Source)
at servlet.InvioXml.doGet(InvioXml.java:65)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)